# How to get absolute path of default place holder image in magento 2

Tags: image, magento2.4.2, placeholder-image

How to get the absolute path of the default placeholder image of the products in Magento 2

I used the below code

```
 $imagePath = $this->imageHelper->getDefaultPlaceholderUrl('image');
```

but it is not giving absolute path,please help

Answer (score 0):

You can use placeholder factory for do this like

```php
$factory = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(\Magento\Catalog\Model\View\Asset\PlaceholderFactory::class);
$placeholder = $factory->create(['type' => 'image']);

// get absolute path with
$placeholder->getPath();
```